# The JavaScript function returns else statement though the search value exists in the array

Tags: javascript

I am trying to search for a userName in the given Array below. The Search function returns true for second element when searching for second element in the array of objects, where as it returns false for first element when searching for first element. It should return true when we search for a existing value in the Array, but the function returns false for first element, true for second element.
I could not find out the mistake I am doing. Even tried using Array.prototype.find() function, but no luck.

```js
//JSON User Information
var userProfiles = [
 {
  "personalInformation" : {
   "userName" : "Chandu3245",
   "firstName" : "Chandrasekar", 
   "secondName" : "Mittapalli", 
   "Gender" : "Male", 
   "email" : "chandxxxxx@gmail.com", 
   "phone" : ["740671xxx8", "8121xxxx74"]
  } 
 },
 {
  "personalInformation" : {
   "userName" : "KounBanega3245",
   "firstName" : "KounBanega", 
   "secondName" : "Karodpati", 
   "Gender" : "Male", 
   "email" : "KounBanega3245@gmail.com", 
   "phone" : ["965781230", "8576123046"]
  }
 }
];
function findUserDataWithUserID (userData, userid){
  var fullName = "";
  //iterates through userData array 
  userData.forEach(function(user){
    //checks for matching userid
    if(user.personalInformation.userName === userid){
   fullName=user.personalInformation.firstName+" "+user.personalInformation.secondName;
    }else{
      fullName = "Userid Not Found";
    }
  });
  return fullName;
}
console.log(findUserDataWithUserID(userProfiles, "Chandu3245"));
```

Comment: Show us your attempt with `Array#find`, and why it didn't work.

Comment: @torazaburo, I coded similarly as the above, but in the place of forEach I wrote array.prototype.find(). When I corrected as per below suggestions it worked fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use the `Array.prototype.some()` method for this.
The `some` method is similar to the `every` method, but works until the return of the function is true. For more information visit: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some

```
function checkProfile (profiles,userid) {
    var message = "Userid not found"
    profiles.some(function(user) {
       if(user.personalInformation.userName === userid) {
            message = user.personalInformation.firstName+" "+user.personalInformation.secondName;
    } 
})
    console.log(message);
};

checkProfile(userProfiles,"KounBanega3245");
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because it is running the `if` case in the first iteration of the `forEach`, then in the second iteration, it processes the second item in the array, causing the `else` clause to run.

A more holistic approach would be to use filter/map/reduce:

```
userProfiles
// Only keep the one that we want
.filter(function(user) {
    return user.personalInformation.userName === userid;
})
// extract the user's name
.map(function(user) {
    return user.personalInformation.firstName + " " + user.personalInformation.secondName;
})
// Get the first (and only) item out of the array
.pop();
```

This does not solve for any error checking (like if the user is not in the original array).